# i can successfully upload gallery image on server using retrofit but not able to upload camera image

Tags: java, android, file-upload, retrofit, okhttp

I can successfully upload gallery image on server using retrofit but not able to upload camera image getting error when i try to upload the camera image.I am new to android and don't have much experience in it.
this is the error i am getting:

> E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
> 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: content == null

on this line:

> RequestBody issueimage =
> RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

```
private void selectImage() {
       final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
       builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
       builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
               if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
               {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                   startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
               }
               else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
               {
                   Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                   startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
               }
               else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }
           }
       });
       builder.show();
   }

   //  email/subject/messagebody/ validation
   private boolean validation() {

       email = edt_email.getText().toString();
       if (!isValidMail(email)) {
           edt_email.setError("Please enter a valid email address");
           edt_email.requestFocus();
           return false;
       }
       if (email == null || email.equals("")) {
           edt_email.setError("Please enter email address");
           edt_email.requestFocus();
           return false;
       }

       subject = edt_subject.getText().toString();

       if (subject == null || subject.equals("")) {
           edt_subject.setError("Please enter subject");
           edt_subject.requestFocus();
           return false;
       }

       msg = edt_msg.getText().toString();

       if (msg == null || msg.equals("")) {
           edt_msg.setError("Please enter message");
           edt_msg.requestFocus();
           return false;
       }



       bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
       //bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath1);
       if (iv_Attach == null ) {
           LT.myToast(context, "Please select Image");
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }

   private boolean isValidMail(String email) {
       boolean check;
       Pattern p;
       Matcher m;

       String EMAIL_STRING = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
               + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

       p = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_STRING);

       m = p.matcher(email);
       check = m.matches();
       return check;
   }
   MultipartBody.Part imagenPerfil = null;
   @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

           if (requestCode == 1) {
               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                   File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                   for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
//                  if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
//                      f = temp;
//
//                      Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
//                      Bitmap myImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImage.getPath());
//                      iv_Attach.setImageBitmap(myImg);
////                        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap)data.getExtras()
////                        .get("data");
////                        iv_Attach.setImageBitmap(photo);
//                      break;
//                  }
                       MultipartBody.Part imagenPerfil = null;
                       if(data != null)
                       {
                           Bitmap selectedImagePath1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                           Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), selectedImagePath1);
                           File file = savebitmap(selectedImagePath1);


                           // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
                           File file1 = new File(getPath(tempUri));
                           String selectedImagePath = file1.getName();
                           //selectedImagePath=getPath(tempUri);

                           // create RequestBody instance from file
                           RequestBody requestFile =
                                   RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), selectedImagePath);
                           // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
                       //  imagenPerfil = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("imagenPerfil", selectedImagePath.getName(), requestFile);

                           System.out.println(selectedImagePath);
                           Log.e("selected img path ","camera img file name"+selectedImagePath);
                           Log.e("selected img path ","camera img"+selectedImagePath);
                           Log.e("selected img path 1","camera ig file path"+selectedImagePath1);
                           System.out.println(selectedImagePath1);
                           ///photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, 80, 80, false);
                           iv_Attach.setImageBitmap(selectedImagePath1);
                       }
                       else{
                           Log.e("Image not set in image view","Not Working..... !!");
                       }

                       break;

                   }
               }

               else{
                   requestPermission();
                   Log.e("Permission","Permission granted !!");
                   // in android version lower than M your method must work
                   Bitmap selectedImagePath1 = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
//                  File file = savebitmap(selectedImagePath1);
                   Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), selectedImagePath1);

                   Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                   selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                   // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH



                   System.out.println(selectedImagePath);
                   Log.e("selected img path ","selected path"+selectedImagePath);
                   Log.e("selected img path 1","selected path"+selectedImagePath1);
                   System.out.println(selectedImagePath1);
                   ///photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(photo, 80, 80, false);
                   //iv_Attach.setImageBitmap(selectedImagePath);
                   iv_Attach.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
               }
           } else if (requestCode == 2) {


               //if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
               Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
               selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
               System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
               iv_Attach.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
           }
       }
   }

   private File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
       String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
       OutputStream outStream = null;
       // String temp = null;
       File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "temp.png");
       if (file.exists()) {
           file.delete();
           file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "temp.png");

       }

       try {
           outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
           bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
           outStream.flush();
           outStream.close();

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
       }
       return file;
   }




   public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
       ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);

       String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
       return Uri.parse(path);
   }

   public String BitMapToString(Bitmap userImage1) {
       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       userImage1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 60, baos);
       byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
       Document_img1 = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
       return Document_img1;
   }


   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   public String getPath(Uri uri) {
       String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
       Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
       int column_index = cursor
               .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       return cursor.getString(column_index);
   }


   private boolean checkPermission() {
       int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
       int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
       int result2 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), CAMERA);
       return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
   }

   private void requestPermission() {

       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

   }

   @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
       switch (requestCode) {
           case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
               if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                   boolean readStorageAccepted = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                   boolean writeStorageAccepted = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                   boolean audioAccepted = grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                   if (readStorageAccepted && writeStorageAccepted && audioAccepted)
                       //Snackbar.make(view, "Permission Granted, Now you can access location data and camera.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Granted, Now you can access .",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   else {
//                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Denied, You cannot access data.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                       //  Snackbar.make(view, "Permission Denied, You cannot access location data and camera.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                           if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                               showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to both the permissions",
                                       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                               if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                                   requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, CAMERA},
                                                           PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                                               }
                                           }
                                       });
                               return;
                           }
                       }

                   }
               }


               break;
       }
   }


   private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
       new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
               .setMessage(message)
               .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
               .create()
               .show();
   }



   private void reportIssueData() {
       //File file = new File(uri.getPath());

       MultipartBody.Part img = null;
       if(selectedImagePath!=null) {
           File file = new File(selectedImagePath);
           Log.i("Register", "image file name " + file.getName());
           // create RequestBody instance from file
           RequestBody requestFile =
                   RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
           // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
           //imagenPerfil = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("imagenPerfil", file.getName(), requestFile);
           MultipartBody.Part issueimage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("issueimage", file.getName(),
                   RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));

       }

       //File file =  new File() ;   // initialize file here

       // add another part within the multipart request
       RequestBody requestEmail =
               RequestBody.create(
                       MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), email);
       // add another part within the multipart request
       RequestBody requestSubject =
               RequestBody.create(
                       MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), subject);
       // add another part within the multipart request
       RequestBody requestmsg =
               RequestBody.create(
                       MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), msg);
       if(file==null)
       {
           file = new File(selectedImagePath);
       }
       RequestBody issueimage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

       HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
       interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
       OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

       Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
               .client(client)
               .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .build();

       Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);


       HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
       params.put("email", email);
       params.put("subject", subject);
       params.put("commment", msg);
       params.put("Image",selectedImagePath);
       params.put("Image",selectedImagePath);
       String strRequestBody = new Gson().toJson(params);
       //try {
       //Map<String, String> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
       final RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.
               parse("application/json"), strRequestBody);

//      api.reportResponse(email,subject,msg,selectedImagePath);
       api.reportResponse(requestEmail,requestSubject,requestmsg,img);
//      Call<ResponseBody> call = api.reportResponse(email,subject,msg,selectedImagePath);
       Call<ResponseBody> call = api.reportResponse(requestEmail,requestSubject,requestmsg,img);
       call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
               try {
                   String s=response.body().string();
                   
                   Toast.makeText(context,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Toast.makeText(context,"img uploaded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Log.e("test","success"+s);
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
               Toast.makeText(context,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Log.e("test","success"+t.getMessage());
           }
       });


   }

   
   public void showResponse(String response) {
       Log.i("response test: ",response);
   }




}
```

Comment: the problem is with fetching the file you captured, as the error says it clear - NullPointerException. So the issue might be within code of capturing image, not in the Upload logic, post code of Camera capture

Comment: @Blu i have edited my complete code plz check where i am doing the mistake.

Comment: Set the debugger over here `if(file==null)
       {
           file = new File(selectedImagePath);
       }` & check if file is actually getting created or not. I guess the selectedImagePath is invalid or theres problem with `permissions`. Have you provided Read & Write permissions? Go to app info of installed application & check for permissions as well.

Comment: @Blu ya i have provided the permissions. File(selectedImagePath); ya that is null but i don't know what i have to do now

Comment: what is the path you getting for 'selectedImagePath'? maybe it's type of content://?